# What does it mean for a binary to be 'munched' after it is compiled?

Tags: c++, vxworks

The title pretty much says it.  This is w/regard to VxWorks; unfortunately, the documentation more or less says that it happens but not why or what purpose it serves.

Comment: Here: http://www.bluedonkey.org/cgi-bin/twiki/bin/view/Books/VxWorksCookbookCPP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a few years since I had to deal with vxworks "munching", but what it does is create the C++ static constructor call table. It apparently isn't needed in the current (6.8+) versions that we're using now. What I recall was from 5.4, I think.

Comment: Is this because the WR Workbench does it without any manual effort or do i realy dont have to munch VxWorks 6.8 binaries?

Comment: We don't much in our 6.8 Makefiles, so I think it is really gone.